# WCF client returns empty array - XML response seems OK

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to create a simple WCF Client (C#) for a web service hosted on our intranet. Using Fiddler and SoapUI I can see the request and response seems OK, but when I run the code an empty array is returned.

I'll try to paste only the relevant lines (and yet will be a LOT of stuff), but feel free to ask if I missed something:

**WSDL**:

```
<s0:definitions name="Workforce_2_1_0" targetNamespace="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:s2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s3="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws" xmlns:s4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
   <s0:documentation>Oracle Data Service Integrator Web Service</s0:documentation>
   <s1:Policy s2:Id="Mtom.xml">
      <wsoma:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:wsoma="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization"/>
   </s1:Policy>
   <wsp:UsingPolicy s0:Required="true"/>
   <s0:types>
      <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws" xmlns:dsns0="http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1" xmlns:s1="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:stns="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws" xmlns:tns="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xs:import namespace="http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1" schemaLocation="http://server123.enterprise.com:31900/MyService/Services/Workforce_2-1-0?SCHEMA%2FMyService%2FResources%2FSchemas%2FWorkForce_2.1"/>
         <xs:element name="getByKey">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
   </s0:types>
   <s0:message name="getByKeyIn">
      <s0:part element="s3:getByKey" name="parameters"/>
   </s0:message>
   <s0:message name="getByKeyOut">
      <s0:part element="s3:getByKeyResponse" name="parameters"/>
   </s0:message>
   <s0:portType name="Workforce_2_1_0PT">
      <s0:operation name="getByKey">
         <s0:input message="s3:getByKeyIn"/>
         <s0:output message="s3:getByKeyOut"/>
      </s0:operation>
   </s0:portType>
   <s0:binding name="Workforce_2_1_0SoapBinding" type="s3:Workforce_2_1_0PT">
      <s4:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsp:Policy>
         <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#Mtom.xml"/>
      </wsp:Policy>
      <s0:operation name="getByKey">
         <s4:operation soapAction="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws/getByKey" style="document"/>
         <s0:input>
            <s4:body use="literal"/>
         </s0:input>
         <s0:output>
            <s4:body use="literal"/>
         </s0:output>
      </s0:operation>
   </s0:binding>
   <s0:service name="Workforce_2_1_0SoapService">
      <s0:port binding="s3:Workforce_2_1_0SoapBinding" name="Workforce_2_1_0SoapPort">
         <s4:address location="http://server123.enterprise.com:31900/MyService/Services/Workforce_2-1-0"/>
      </s0:port>
   </s0:service>
</s0:definitions>
```

**Binding configuration**:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="Workforce_2_1_0SoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

**Endpoint**:

```
<endpoint address="http://server123.enterprise.com:31900/MyService/Services/Workforce_2-1-0"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Workforce_2_1_0SoapBinding"
    contract="Workforce.Workforce_2_1_0PT" name="Workforce_2_1_0SoapPort" />
```

**Request** (through Fiddler):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <getByKey xmlns="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws">
            <key>ABCDEFGH</key>
        </getByKey>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Response** (through Fiddler):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getByKeyResponse xmlns:ns='ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws'>
            <ns0:basicWorkforce xmlns:ns0="http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1">
                <ns0:key>ABCDEFGH</ns0:key>
                <ns0:name>JUAN PABLO MONTOYA</ns0:name>
            </ns0:basicWorkforce>
        </ns:getByKeyResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Client code**:

```
Workforce_2_1_0PTClient client = new Workforce_2_1_0PTClient();

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUsername";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";

var result = client.getByKey("ABCDEFGH");
```

**EDIT:** Including proxy code, generated by Visual Studio

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getByKey", WrapperNamespace="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getByKeyRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws", Order=0)]
    public string key;

    public getByKeyRequest() {
    }

    public getByKeyRequest(string key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getByKeyResponse", WrapperNamespace="ld:Logical/Workforce_2_1_0_ws", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getByKeyResponse {
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("basicWorkforce")]
    public basicWorkforce[] basicWorkforce;

    public getByKeyResponse() {
    }

    public getByKeyResponse(basicWorkforce[] basicWorkforce) {
        this.basicWorkforce = basicWorkforce;
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1")]
public partial class basicWorkforce : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string keyField;

    private string nameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string key {
        get {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set {
            this.keyField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("key");
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }
}
```

Even if the response contains one `basicWorkforce` element, the `result` variable is an empty array of `basicWorkforce`.

Sorry about the long post and thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally did it!
For anyone facing the same problem, it lies on the namespaces. In this case, on the array returned by `getByKeyResponse`.

So, I just replaced this:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("basicWorkforce")]
    public basicWorkforce[] basicWorkforce;
```

with this:

```
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("basicWorkforce", Namespace = "http://schemata.enterprise.biz/hr/2.1")]
    public basicWorkforce[] basicWorkforce;
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I was tried this solution but it is not corrected. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450237/wsdl-web-service-returns-empty-array-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Have you made Collection Type to System.Array
Its in the Add Service References -> Advanced
 
OR 
under Service References -> Configure Service References.

Comment: Yes, it's set to System.Array, but I also tried System.Generic.List with no luck.