# WSDL Web Service returns empty array from C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asp.net-web-api, wsdl

I am using a web service with this address: 
https://api.n11.com/ws/CityService.wsdl

The service has a method 'GetCities'. You can test it with http://wsdlbrowser.com/

The problem is when I get Cities from C#, it returns an array of 81 elements
but 'cityId' and 'cityName' gets null.

[image]

Please help!

My code is shown below:

```
        GetCitiesRequest request = new GetCitiesRequest();
        CityServicePortClient port = new CityServicePortClient();

        GetCitiesResponse getCitiesResponse = port.GetCities(request);

        var list = getCitiesResponse.cities;
```

Comment: Can you show your code too.

Comment: I experienced the same issue. There was an empty property in our response that was not shown in the wsdl we received which caused an incorrect ordering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!!!

Visual Studio is messing up the `Order` parameter on `XmlElementAttribute`, so, in your `References.cs` file change the following:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
public long cityId
```

to

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
public long cityId
```

and

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
public string cityCode
```

to

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
public string cityCode
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But what is the Order parameter?

Comment: It's the order of the field in the XML response. It's needed for deserialization. The way it was, it's expected to return `<cityId>1</cityId><cityCode>123</cityCode>`, but, in fact, it was returning `<cityCode>123</cityCode><cityId>1</cityId>`, hence you had to switch the orders between the two fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same behavior.

My assumption is, that the service: https://api.n11.com/ws/CityService.wsdl is not returning a value.